# SQL query to group by month part of timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, group-by

I'm really bad at SQL queries but I'm learning so please forgive this question.

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP, SUM( electricity ) AS electricity,  `siteID` 
FROM table
WHERE (
MONTH(  `TimeStamp` ) =10)
GROUP BY siteID
```

My table looks like:

```
#########################################
# Id # SiteID # TimeStamp  # Elecricity #
# 0  # 100    # 10/08/2012 # 50         #
# 1  # 98     # 10/08/2012 # 32         #
# 2  # 100    # 10/09/2012 # 96         #
# 3  # 94     # 10/09/2012 # 25         #
# 4  # 100    # 10/10/2012 # 100        #
# 5  # 100    # 10/11/2012 # 55         #
#########################################
```

What I am trying to do is to sum up all of the days of each month of each site, so that I will have one answer per site and month. So in this example the query should return the sum of the electricity values for siteID 100 because they're all in month 10, the same for siteID 98 and 94.

Thanks

Comment: . . The query looks like it does what you intend (assuming you don't have records from multiple years).  Are you having a problem with it?

Comment: Assuming only one site for this question...
Do you really want one record per month? OR one record for each month in each YEAR?
Said another way, do you want Jan 2012 and Jan 2013 to be seperate records or be combined into a sinlge record?

Comment: As recommended by Brian below, I have added a field to specify which year I want; I had previously overlooked that issue. And Gordon, this was returning only one value for each site, I wanted a value for each site/month combination, as achieved below

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
SELECT month('TIMESTAMP'), SUM( electricity ) AS electricity,  `siteID` 
FROM table
WHERE (
MONTH(  `TimeStamp` ) =10)
GROUP BY siteID, month('TIMESTAMP')
```

This will work.  One thing that you have to think about is that month is not unique.  Oct, 2012, in this case, is the same as Oct 2013.  You might want to add another column for year.