# Grouping by Month of TimeStamp

Tags: sql, timestamp, teradata, group-by

I am attempting to group by twice, once by an individual level field and then by the month of the timestamp field.

Little new to SQL but here's what I came up with after reading another SO post here: [SQL query to group by month part of timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087659/sql-query-to-group-by-month-part-of-timestamp)

```
SELECT
        VwNIMUserDim.USER_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
         VwNIMEventFct.NIM_USER_ID, 
         SUM(CASE WHEN NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID = 880 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS APP_OPEN,
         SUM(CASE WHEN NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID = 881 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS AUTODL_SETTINGS_SAVE,
         SUM(CASE WHEN NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID = 882 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS AUTO_QUERY_CONFIRM,
         SUM(CASE WHEN NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID = 883 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ISSUE_CLOSE,
         SUM(CASE WHEN NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID = 884 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ISSUE_DOWNLOAD,
         SUM(CASE WHEN NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID = 885 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ISSUE_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE,
         SUM(CASE WHEN NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID = 886 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PICKER_SEND_PICKS
 FROM RDMAVWSANDBOX.VwNIMEventFct
 GROUP BY NIM_USER_ID, MONTH('EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP')
```

The error message returned by my SQL client, Teradata, says:
"SELECT FAILED Error 3706 Syntax error expected something in between ',' and the MONTH keyword.

This is my first time doing two things: Grouping By twice and using the Month function.

What am I doing wrong here? How do I group by email address users in each month?

Comment: first off the tics around the field make it a string.  I don't think you want that. second, I think you need to have the field as part of the select to group by it depending on the version and flavor of SQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no MONTH function in Teradata/Standard SQL, it's EXTRACT(YEAR/MONTH/DAY/HOUR/MINUTE/SECOND):

```
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query as written will result in a PRODUCT (Cartesian) JOIN between the VwNIMUserDIm and VwNIMEventFct tables (views). I have taken the liberty to modify the SQL based on your comments to the previous response:

```
SELECT
        User_.USER_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
         Event_.NIM_USER_ID, 
         Event_.EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP(FORMAT 'yyyy-mm')(char(7)) AS EVENT_MONTH, 
         SUM(CASE WHEN Event_.NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID = 880 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS APP_OPEN,
         SUM(CASE WHEN Event_.NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID = 881 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS AUTODL_SETTINGS_SAVE,
         SUM(CASE WHEN Event_.NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID = 882 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS AUTO_QUERY_CONFIRM,
         SUM(CASE WHEN Event_.NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID = 883 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ISSUE_CLOSE,
         SUM(CASE WHEN Event_.NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID = 884 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ISSUE_DOWNLOAD,
         SUM(CASE WHEN Event_.NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID = 885 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ISSUE_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE,
         SUM(CASE WHEN Event_.NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID = 886 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PICKER_SEND_PICKS
 FROM RDMAVWSANDBOX.VwNIMEventFct Event_
 JOIN RDMAVWSANDBOX.VwNIMUserDim User_
   ON Event_.NIM_USER_ID = User_.NIM_USER_ID
 GROUP BY 1,2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly depending on database origin (MSSQL, mySQL, Oracle, DB2, Etc)

```
SELECT
        VwNIMUserDim.USER_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
         VwNIMEventFct.NIM_USER_ID, 
         MONTH(EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP),
         SUM(CASE WHEN NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID = 880 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS APP_OPEN,
         SUM(CASE WHEN NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID = 881 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS AUTODL_SETTINGS_SAVE,
         SUM(CASE WHEN NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID = 882 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS AUTO_QUERY_CONFIRM,
         SUM(CASE WHEN NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID = 883 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ISSUE_CLOSE,
         SUM(CASE WHEN NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID = 884 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ISSUE_DOWNLOAD,
         SUM(CASE WHEN NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID = 885 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ISSUE_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE,
         SUM(CASE WHEN NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID = 886 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PICKER_SEND_PICKS
 FROM RDMAVWSANDBOX.VwNIMEventFct
 GROUP BY NIM_USER_ID, MONTH(EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Added the MONTH(EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP)and removed the quotes but still no joy. Same error message except it refers to the 4th row now (MONTH(EVENT_... - Teradata highlights the row with errors)

Comment: I managed to get this working with some more research: 
 EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP(FORMAT 'yyyy-mm')(char(7))