# Want to calculate leave days month wise in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Scenario is if Employee apply for leave: From Date is "2016-03-30" and To Date is "2016-04-02" so Output will be "In 3rd month leave days should be 2" and "In 4th month leave days should be 1".
I have Table:

```
UserID          FromDate      ToDate     LeaveDuration
------------------------------------------------------
0001            20/03/2016    21/03/2016       1
0001            30/03/2016    02/04/2016       2
```

In 2nd record 2 days should be consider in 3rd month and 1 day should be consider in 4th month.
I tried below query:

```
select sum(datediff(ToDate,FromDate)) as Total
from wp_ag_assign_leave
where UserId=18
  and LeaveType="Carry Forward Leave"
  and (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURDATE())=EXTRACT(MONTH FROM FromDate)
  OR EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURDATE())=EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ToDate))
```

Please Help me to solve it

Comment: What? Please update your question with some samples of data and expected output

Comment: try with a GROUP BY on month, a helpful link http://stackoverflow.com/a/18087708/4229270

Comment: And the output your query provides as opposed to what you expect.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9888386/4229270

Comment: @shadow I am very new to mysql so please help to solve this query

Comment: I think 2014 - 2016 is going to be more than 2 or 3 days

Comment: @Strawberry  sorry my mistake it is 2016 not 2014.

Comment: if i calculate salary for 3rd month then 2 days should be deducted from 3rd month and 1 day should be deducted from 4th month.....

Comment: do you need to take into account closed days and weekends ?

Comment: more seriously, there's something weird in your example, and it lacks an important rule: indeed, first line 20/03 and 21/03 make 1 day. And second line 30/03 31/03 01/04 and 04/04 make 2 days. It should make 3, unless closed days are taken into account (as I said)

Answer (score 1):

you may want to precise some dates usind e.g `date_add` but here's what I've done :

```
select month,
       sum(duration) as 'LeaveDays'       
from (
  select if(month(FromDate)=month(ToDate),month(FromDate),'other') as 'month',
        if(month(FromDate)=month(ToDate),datediff(Todate, FromDate),'other')  as 'duration'
 from wp_ag_assign_leave
 UNION   
 select  if(month(FromDate)!=month(ToDate),month(FromDate),'other') as 'month',
           if(month(FromDate)!=month(ToDate),datediff(last_day(FromDate),FromDate),'other') as 'duration'
 from wp_ag_assign_leave
 UNION
 select  if(month(FromDate)!=month(ToDate),month(ToDate),'other') as 'month',
           if(month(FromDate)!=month(ToDate),dateDiff(ToDate,last_day(FromDate)),'other') as 'duration'
 from wp_ag_assign_leave
) as parseMonths
where month!='other'
group by month
order by month;
```

The 3 `SELECT`in the `UNION` statement :
- 1 the dates are in the same month, simple difference
- 2 the dates are NOT in the same month : 1st month's part
- 2 the dates are NOT in the same month : 2nd month's part

Answer (score -3):

As per scenario calculate month and year wise leave days

```
select user_id,ymonth,
       sum(duration) as 'LeaveDays'     
from (
  select user_id,if(EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM leave_from)=EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM leave_to),EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM leave_from),'other') as 'ymonth',
        if(EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM leave_from)=EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM leave_to),datediff(leave_to, leave_from)+1,'other')  as 'duration'
 from leave_application
 UNION ALL  
 select user_id, if(EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM leave_from)!=EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM leave_to),EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM leave_from),'other') as 'ymonth',
           if(EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM leave_from)!=EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM leave_to),datediff(last_day(leave_from),leave_from)+1,'other') as 'duration'
 from leave_application
 UNION ALL
 select user_id, if(EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM leave_from)!=EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM leave_to),EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM leave_to),'other') as 'ymonth',
           if(EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM leave_from)!=EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM leave_to),dateDiff(leave_to,last_day(leave_from)),'other') as 'duration'
 from leave_application 
) as parseMonths
where ymonth!='other' 
group by ymonth
order by ymonth
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).